# Api-platform prevent IRI @ID serialization when null

Tags: api-platform.com

**Short question**: I want to be able to serialize an `ApiResource` that does not have an ID yet.

I recently upgraded to api-platform v3.2, from v2.6. One of the 'features' that used to work was I could serialize a resource that did not have an ID. This is very useful in my case, because I often serialize a un-persisted entity that is outputted to an HTML form before its sent to the client. The client side then acts on it as-needed. But in v3.0 I simply get an exception:

> Unable to generate an IRI for the item

in v2.6, it would serialize just fine like this:

```json
{
  "@context": "/my/api/contexts/ResourceName",
  "@id": "/my/api/resource/", // notice lack of actual ID value
  ...
}
```

I have a custom `Normalizer` that does certain things for my app, and within that I was able to hack something to make it so that no `@id` is generated for resources with a null ID, but this doesn't feel right.

```php
// remove iri catch for next nested object
if (($context['_app_ignore_iri'] ?? null) && $context['_app_ignore_iri'] !== $object) {
    unset($context['_app_ignore_iri'], $context['force_iri_generation'], $context['iri']);
}
// do not create IRI if the object has no ID; not sure of a better way to do this with api-platform v3.0+
if (method_exists($object, 'getId') && $object->getId() === null) {
    $context['_app_ignore_iri'] = $object;
    $context['force_iri_generation'] = false;
    $context['iri'] = true; //str_replace('\\', '/', get_class($object)) . '/0'; // could be anything
}
$norm = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
if (null === ($norm['@id'] ?? null)) { //&& !($context['skip_null_values'] ?? true)) {
    $norm['@id'] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this attribute to avoid generating an IRI

```
#[ApiProperty(genId: false)]
```

Comment: That would remove all ID generation for the resource. In my use-case I only want the ID not to generate if the ID is null.